# c# RTB - paste plain text without colours/fonts?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am using Rich Text object in my C# application. The only issue I am having is that when user pastes formated text from another app, it remains formated which I cannot have. Is there any way how to paste only string and ignore formatting?
Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas Added a second code-example that inserts the Clipboard content at the current insertion point in the RichTextBox, then updates the insertion point to just after the added text. Second example also illustrates use of Suspend/Resume Layout to avoid blinking effect of re-setting content of RichTextBox. Be sure and test with a variety of types of formatted input : again, this is NOT fully tested to a level where I'd use it in production code without further testing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming WinForms : try this : define a RichTextBox with a KeyDown event handler like this :

Append-only example :

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) 
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += (string)Clipboard.GetData("Text"); 
            e.Handled = true; 
        }
    }
```

[Edit]

Add Clipboard RTF to RichTextBox at current insertion point (selection start) example :

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)  
    { 
            // suspend layout to avoid blinking
            richTextBox2.SuspendLayout();

            // get insertion point
            int insPt = richTextBox2.SelectionStart;

            // preserve text from after insertion pont to end of RTF content
            string postRTFContent = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(insPt);

            // remove the content after the insertion point
            richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, insPt);

            // add the clipboard content and then the preserved postRTF content
            richTextBox2.Text += (string)Clipboard.GetData("Text") + postRTFContent;

            // adjust the insertion point to just after the inserted text
            richTextBox2.SelectionStart = richTextBox2.TextLength - postRTFContent.Length;

            // restore layout
            richTextBox2.ResumeLayout();

            // cancel the paste
            e.Handled = true;
    } 
}
```

[End Edit]

Note 0 : The pasted in text *is* going to assume the current style settings in effect for the RichTextBox : if you have 'ForeGround color set to 'Blue : the pasted in text is going to be in blue.

Note 1 : This is something I knocked together quickly, and tested only a few times by creating some multi-colored and weirdly formatted RTF for the clipboard using WordPad : then pasting into into the RichTextBox1 at run-time : it did strip away all the color, indenting, etc.

Since it's not fully tested, *use caution.*

Note 2 : This will not handle the case of 'Insert or 'Paste via Context Menu, obviously.

Welcome all critiques of this answer, and will immediately take it down if it's not "on the mark."

Comment: Keep in mind that the code above is just appending the text to the end of the current RTF contents; for real-world use you'll probably want to handle the case where you want the pasted text to insert at the current insertion point in the RichTextBox (very easy to do). I've tested the code to make sure no error is thrown if the Clipboard is "Empty" : no problem there.

Comment: I'm thinking a solution geared at constantly filtering the contents. If rich text arrives in an inhuman amount of time (i.e. pasted in) then convert to regular text.

Comment: when you have selected something and press Ctrl+V, you expect old selection to be replaced with clipboard contents, but in your solution it's added. By the way @nQk 2-lines solution works great )

Comment: Small correction: postRTFContent should actually be filled with `richTextBox2.Text.Substring(insPt + richTextBox2.SelectionLength)`, so that selected text is replaced on paste as it should. Also, the legacy paste shortcut Shift+Insert should be added as key combination too.

Comment: Also, I found that despite the `SuspendLayout()`, changing the Text will update the control anyway. The best way to prevent this is to do as few changes of the Text property as possible, by composing the string first and then just assigning it once.

Answer (score 33):

Add a handler to the `KeyDown`-event to intercept the standard paste and manually insert only the plain text:

```
private void rtb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        ((RichTextBox)sender).Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat("Text"));
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh. Perfect. Needs Shift+Insert handling too though.

Comment: @Nyerguds: if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) || (e.Shift && e.KeyCode==Keys.Insert))

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for a plaintext-only `richtextbox` but haven't found the solution online.

Why Plaintext-only `RichTextBox` instead of a `TextBox`? For example because `RichTextBox` has usable undo/redo functionality and much more.

Finally I found a perfect solution by digging into the C header files of the richedit control: A `RichTextBox` can be switched into plaintext mode, after that it doesn't accept formatted text and images and similar things from the clipboard and behaves like a normal `TextBox` formattingwise. Fancy things like images can not be pasted and it pastes formatted text by removing the formatting.

```
class PlainRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    const int WM_USER = 0x400;
    const int EM_SETTEXTMODE = WM_USER + 89;
    const int EM_GETTEXTMODE = WM_USER + 90;

    // EM_SETTEXTMODE/EM_GETTEXTMODE flags
    const int TM_PLAINTEXT = 1;
    const int TM_RICHTEXT = 2;          // Default behavior 
    const int TM_SINGLELEVELUNDO = 4;
    const int TM_MULTILEVELUNDO = 8;    // Default behavior 
    const int TM_SINGLECODEPAGE = 16;
    const int TM_MULTICODEPAGE = 32;    // Default behavior 

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    bool m_PlainTextMode;

    // If this property doesn't work for you from the designer for some reason
    // (for example framework version...) then set this property from outside
    // the designer then uncomment the Browsable and DesignerSerializationVisibility
    // attributes and set the Property from your component initializer code
    // that runs after the designer's code.
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    //[Browsable(false)]
    //[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool PlainTextMode
    {
        get
        {
            return m_PlainTextMode;
        }
        set
        {
            m_PlainTextMode = value;
            if (IsHandleCreated)
            {
                IntPtr mode = value ? (IntPtr)TM_PLAINTEXT : (IntPtr)TM_RICHTEXT;
                SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETTEXTMODE, mode, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // For some reason it worked for me only if I manipulated the created
        // handle before calling the base method.
        PlainTextMode = m_PlainTextMode;
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from pasztorpisti worked like a charm for me. Since I'm using vb.net I thought I'd post my translated code for others:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyRichTextBox
    Inherits Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

    Public Const WM_USER As Integer = &H400
    Public Const EM_SETTEXTMODE As Integer = WM_USER + 89
    Public Const EM_GETTEXTMODE As Integer = WM_USER + 90

    'EM_SETTEXTMODE/EM_GETTEXTMODE flags
    Public Const TM_PLAINTEXT As Integer = 1
    Public Const TM_RICHTEXT As Integer = 2          ' Default behavior 
    Public Const TM_SINGLELEVELUNDO As Integer = 4
    Public Const TM_MULTILEVELUNDO As Integer = 8    ' Default behavior 
    Public Const TM_SINGLECODEPAGE As Integer = 16
    Public Const TM_MULTICODEPAGE As Integer = 32    ' Default behavior

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private _plainTextMode As Boolean = False
    <DefaultValue(False),
      Browsable(True)>
    Public Property PlainTextMode As Boolean
        Get
            Return _plainTextMode
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _plainTextMode = value

            If (Me.IsHandleCreated) Then
                Dim mode As IntPtr = If(value, TM_PLAINTEXT, TM_RICHTEXT)
                SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETTEXTMODE, mode, IntPtr.Zero)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        'For some reason it worked for me only if I manipulated the created
        'handle before calling the base method.
        Me.PlainTextMode = _plainTextMode

        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the RichTextBox has a `SelectionFont` property so you can for instance do the following:

```
Font courier;
courier = new Font("Courier new", 10f, FontStyle.Regular);
myRtb.SelectionFont = courier;
myRtb.Font = courier; //So the typed text is also the same font
```

If a text gets pasted, it will be automatically formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = (string)Clipboard.GetData("Text");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by udpating the font and colour for the whole RTB when its contents are changed. This works fine for me as the entry box does not need to deal with huge amounts of text.

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtRtb.TextChanged += txtRtb_TextChanged;
}

void txtRtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;
    rtb.SelectAll();
    rtb.SelectionFont = rtb.Font;
    rtb.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
    rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
private void OnCommandExecuting(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Documents.RichTextBoxCommands.CommandExecutingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command is PasteCommand)
    {
        //override paste when clipboard comes from out of RichTextBox (plain text)
        var documentFromClipboard = ClipboardEx.GetDocumentFromClipboard("RadDocumentGUID");
        if (documentFromClipboard == null)
        {
            (sender as RichTextBox).Insert(Clipboard.GetText());
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this that is working well for me:

```
private bool updatingText;

public MyForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    inputTextBox.TextChanged += inputTextBox_TextChanged;
}
private void inputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (updatingText)
    {
        return;
    }
    updatingText = true;
    try
    {
        var i = inputTextBox.SelectionStart;
        var text = inputTextBox.Text;
        inputTextBox.Rtf = "";
        inputTextBox.Text = text;
        inputTextBox.SelectionStart = i;
    }
    catch (Exception){}
    updatingText = false;
}
```

Since the `Text` property is inherently without formatting resetting the RTF text then setting the text property to the raw input removes any of the special items that may have been pasted in.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, but everything in the clipboard is in plain text when application is open.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string paste = Clipboard.GetText();
            Clipboard.SetText(paste);
        }
```