# RichTextBox ignore formatting on paste

Tags: c#, winforms, format, richtextbox

I have two RichTextBoxes (input and output). If I copy text with color from output and paste into input, the color of the text gets pasted as well. Is it possible to make the input-TextBox ignore formatting upon paste? I don't want colored text in the input-TextBox.

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF? Do you just care about ctrl+V or pastes performed via the integrated menu?

Comment: Usually ctrl+shift+V does unformatted paste. Not sure it works for RichTextBoxes on your platform (whatever that is), but it's worth a try.

Comment: Windows Forms. I usually just do ctrl+c, ctrl+v - so I guess that's all I care about. Would be nice to have complete coverage, though. I was hoping there was a property that could be set to 'False' to solve this.

I tried using ctrl+shift+c / v, it didn't work. (It still pasted the color.)

Comment: Detect a paste: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618162/detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box then change the content to text:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037827/c-sharp-rtb-paste-plain-text-without-colours-fonts. For full coverage you would need to handle the WM_PASTE sent to the RTBs parent.